# personal folder in outlook stored on network share available on iphone?

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, email, exchange-activesync, ms-office

I am looking to swap out a BlackBerry for an iPhone from Verizon. On the BlackBerry we use an older version of the desktop synchronization software and I can access personal folders (Outlook 2007 and Exchange Server 2007) stored on a network share. Can you do that from an iPhone?

Comment: Do you mean when you're on that local network, or from outside via the Internet?

Comment: It resides on a departmental share drive on the network.  That drive is mapped through group policy. The personal folders are, of course, mapped to the desktop inside outlook 2007.  The BB synch manager allows those folders linked in outlook to also be synched to the BB.  Can the Iphone (or a 3rd party app) do the same? While on the BB if you move an email from your inbox into a folder in your personal folder it moves it on the desktop as well.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this works while using a VPN. The iPhone talks to the Exchange group policies, and can use all the mail folders (although, [IMAP may be necessary](http://www.everythingicafe.com/forum/iphone/i-managed-to-get-all-of-my-exchange-folders-4371.html) for this). For more info, see [this Apple doc](http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iPhone_Business.pdf) (page 9).